# Rerouting Ports for a Gameserver

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port, minecraft

I want to redirect a port, so say all traffic coming in on subdomain.xyz.com:2233 is rerouted to an ip 10.13.15.34:3344 (for example) I have access to an ubuntu box if needed, and access to xyz.com's DNS records, but i cannot change the port on the ip. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: forwarding ports isn't done from the web server or the DNS records you need access to the router or firewall. Make and model will help.

Comment: The gameserver isn't home hosted, its from a proffessional host. I need the IP and port changed to a subdomain and different port. I have access to the domain, and a linux box to route through, idk if it helps/is needed :)

Comment: Yes the linux box as a router is pretty important...

Comment: The linux box isn't hosting the server, I just need info on how to route the ip through the server to change the ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point subdomain.xyz.com to a Linux box you control, and then configure it to DNAT the packets to the server. First add an A record for subdomain.xyz.com pointing to the Linux box. Then setup iptables with something like this:

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --protocol tcp --dport 2233 --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.13.15.34:3344
iptables --append FORWARD --protocol tcp --ports 3344 --jump ACCEPT
```

Comment: You should accept his answer so we know a good solution was found to your problem :)